# execute a command within docker swarm service

Tags: docker-swarm

1. Initialize swarm mode:

   ```
   root@ip-172-31-44-207:/home/ubuntu# docker swarm init --advertise-addr 172.31.44.207

   Swarm initialized: current node (4mj61oxcc8ulbwd7zedxnz6ce) is now a manager.

   To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:
   ```
2. Join the second node:

   ```
   docker swarm join \
   --token SWMTKN-1-4xvddif3wf8tpzcg23tem3zlncth8460srbm7qtyx5qk3ton55-6g05kuek1jhs170d8fub83vs5 \
   172.31.44.207:2377
   ```

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.

```
# start 2 services
docker service create continuumio/miniconda3 

docker service create --name redis redis:3.0.6


root@ip-172-31-44-207:/home/ubuntu# docker service ls
ID            NAME        REPLICAS  IMAGE                   COMMAND
2yc1xjmita67  miniconda3  0/1       continuumio/miniconda3
c3ptcf2q9zv2  redis       1/1       redis:3.0.6
```

As shown above, redis has it's replica while miniconda does **not** seem to be **replicated**.

I do usually log-in to miniconda container to type these commands:

```
/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser
```

The problem is that `docker exec -it XXX bash` command does not work with swarm mode.

Comment: The 0 replicas means the container failed to start. I recommend you configure a logging driver (e.g. syslog driver) on your docker daemon since by default it swallows all output of the containers. It's probably restarting over and over again and you'll want to know why. If that is the case, you won't be able to attach to it and fix it; you'll need to fix the docker service command instead so that it doesn't exit with an error.

Answer (score 67):

You can execute commands by filtering container name without needing to pass the entire swarm container hash, just by the service name. Like this:

`docker exec $(docker ps -q -f name=servicename) ls`

Comment: this should be the recommended approach. if you need anything more, can easily script off of this little snippet.

Comment: This should not be a recommended approach.
The service may have multiple replicas and that command would run only in one of them, if at all with many hashes

Comment: If you have several replicas you can use `docker exec $(docker ps -q -f name=servicename | head -n1) ls`. Of course this only runs in one of them.

Answer (score 46):

There is one liner for accessing corresponding instance of the service for localhost:

```
docker exec -ti stack_myservice.1.$(docker service ps -f 'name=stack_myservice.1' stack_myservice -q --no-trunc | head -n1) /bin/bash
```

It is tested on PowerShell, but bash should be the same. The oneliner accesses the first instance, but replace '1' with the number of the instance you want to access in two places to get other one.

More complex example is for distributed case:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

exec_task=$1
exec_instance=$2

strindex() { 
  x="${1%%$2*}"
  [[ "$x" = "$1" ]] && echo -1 || echo "${#x}"
}

parse_node() {
  read title
  id_start=0
  name_start=`strindex "$title" NAME`
  image_start=`strindex "$title" IMAGE`
  node_start=`strindex "$title" NODE`
  dstate_start=`strindex "$title" DESIRED`
  id_length=name_start
  name_length=`expr $image_start - $name_start`
  node_length=`expr $dstate_start - $node_start`

  read line
  id=${line:$id_start:$id_length}
  name=${line:$name_start:$name_length}
  name=$(echo $name)
  node=${line:$node_start:$node_length}
  echo $name.$id
  echo $node
}

if true; then 
   read fn 
   docker_fullname=$fn
   read nn
   docker_node=$nn 
fi < <( docker service ps -f name=$exec_task.$exec_instance --no-trunc -f desired-state=running $exec_task | parse_node )

echo "Executing in $docker_node $docker_fullname" 

eval `docker-machine env $docker_node`

docker exec -ti $docker_fullname /bin/bash
```

This script could be used later as:

```
swarm_bash stack_task 1
```

It just execute bash on required node.

Comment: The one-liner needs --no-trunc after the -q

Comment: regarding the bash script ```$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE
jiecd0kb524e        bar                 replicated          3/3                 jwilder/whoami:latest``` and when I call it ```$ ./swarm_bash bar 1
Executing in swarmm-agentpublic-31109991000004 bar.1.vj6lqkz4wi03hn7hr6574cipg
Host does not exist: "swarmm-agentpublic-31109991000004"
Error response from daemon: No such container: bar.1.vj6lqkz4wi03hn7hr6574cipg``` Can I really exec in swarm mode? The one liner also doesn't works for me

Comment: Needs --no-trunc and head -n1

Comment: I got an error on the `docker-machine` eval using a recent install of `docker-ce` but the rest of the script worked swimmingly.

Comment: This answer does only work for localhost. Though stated, perhaps highlight the fact a bit more. This solution is no general answer to execute a command in a swarm service. For bash, the default docker TAB-key completion does the job on localhost too: https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/#bash

Comment: In case you don't have docker-machine but ssh access, a `ssh -tt $docker_node sudo docker exec -ti $docker_fullname /bin/bash` should do.

Comment: The complex script can be made simpler by using the --format option
`--format="{{.Node}}"` for the node name

Answer (score 24):

---

EDIT 2017-10-06:

Nowadays you can create the overlay network with `--attachable` flag to enable any container to join the network. This is great feature as it allows a lot of flexibility.

E.g.

```
$ docker network create --attachable --driver overlay my-network
$ docker service create --network my-network --name web --publish 80:80 nginx
$ docker run --network=my-network -ti alpine sh
(in alpine container) $  wget -qO- web

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
....
```

---

You are right, you cannot run `docker exec` on docker swarm mode service. But you can still find out, which node is running the container and then run exec directly on the container. E.g.

```
docker service ps miniconda3  # find out, which node is running the container
eval `docker-machine env <node name here>`
docker ps  # find out the container id of miniconda
docker exec -it <container id here> sh
```

In your case you first have to find out, why service cannot get the miniconda container up. Maybe running `docker service ps miniconda3` shows some helpful error messages..?

Answer (score 17):

**Using the Docker API**

Right now, Docker does not provide an API like `docker service exec` or `docker stack exec` for this. But regarding this, there already exists two issues dealing with this functionality:

- [github.com - moby/moby - Docker service exec](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27552)
- [github.com - docker/swarmkit - Support for executing into a task](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1895)

(Regarding the first issue, for me, it was not directly clear that this issue deals with exactly this kind of functionality. But [Exec for Swarm](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31548) was closed and marked as duplicate of the [Docker service exec](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27552) issue.)

**Using Docker daemon over HTTP**

As mentioned by [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639230/1885518) on [run docker exec from swarm manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638869/run-docker-exec-from-swarm-manager/), you could also configure the Docker daemon to use HTTP and than connect to every node without the need of ssh. But you should protect this using [TLS authentication](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) which is already integrated into Docker. Afterwards you would be able to execute the `docker exec` like this:

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem \
    -H=$HOST:2376 exec $containerId $cmd
```

**Using skopos-plugin-swarm-exec**

There exists a github project which claims to solve the problem and provide the desired functionality binding the docker daemon:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    datagridsys/skopos-plugin-swarm-exec \
    task-exec <taskID> <command> [<arguments>...]
```

As far as I can see, this works by creating another container at same node where the container reside where the `docker exec` should by executed on. On this node this container mounts the docker daemon socket to be able to execute `docker exec` there locally.
For more information have a look at: [skopos-plugin-swarm-exec](https://github.com/datagridsys/skopos-plugin-swarm-exec)

**Using docker swarm helpers**

There is also another project called [docker swarm helpers](https://github.com/rdxmb/docker_swarm_helpers) which seems to be more or less a wrapper around `ssh` and `docker exec`.

Reference:

- https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1895#issuecomment-302147604
- https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1895#issuecomment-358925313

Comment: This is a great reference and much more detailed response on the problem. Thank you! ‍♂️

Answer (score 11):

You can jump in a Swarm node and list the docker containers running using:

```
docker container ls
```

That will give you the container name in a format similar to:

```
containername.1.q5k89uctyx27zmntkcfooh68f
```

You can then use the regular exec option to run commands on it:

```
docker container exec -it containername.1.q5k89uctyx27zmntkcfooh68f bash
```

Comment: To be clear, that will only give access to services running in that particular node.

Comment: Could be useful to explain what *jumping in Swarm node* means exactly.

Comment: I think "jump in a Swarm node" means running exec interactively, like getting a `sh` or `psql` prompt that you can work with.

Answer (score 8):

created a small script for our docker swarm cluster.
this script takes 3 params. first is the service you want to connect to second the task you want to run this can be `/bin/bash` or any other process you want to run. Third is optional and will fill -c option for bash or sh

-n is optional to force it to connect to a node

it retrieves the node that runs the service and runs the command.

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

task=${1}
service=$2
bash=$3

serviceID=$(sudo docker service ps -f name=$service -f desired-state=running $service -q --no-trunc |head -n1)
node=$(sudo docker service ps -f name=$service -f desired-state=running $service --format="{{.Node}}"| head -n1 )

sudo docker -H $node exec -it $service".1."$serviceID $bash -c "$task"
```

**note**: this requires the docker nodes to accept tcp connections by exposing docker on port 2375 on the worker nodes

Answer (score 8):

For those who have multiple replicas and just want to run a command within any of them, here is another shortcut:

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name=SERVICE_NAME | head -1) bash
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote script to exec command in docker swarm by service name. For example it can be used in cron. Also you can use bash pipelines and passes all params to `docker exec` command. But works only on same node where service started. I wish it could help someone

```
#!/bin/bash
# swarm-exec.sh
set -e

for ((i=1;i<=$#;i++)); do
    val=${!i}
    if [ ${val:0:1} != "-" ]; then
        service_id=$(docker ps -q -f "name=$val");
        if [[ $service_id  == "" ]]; then
            echo "Container $val not found!";
            exit 1;
        fi
        docker exec ${@:1:$i-1} $service_id ${@:$i+1:$#};
        exit 0;
    fi
done
echo "Usage: $0 [OPTIONS] SERVICE_NAME COMMAND [ARG...]";
exit 1;
```

Example of using:

```
./swarm-exec.sh app_postgres pg_dump -Z 9 -F p -U postgres app > /backups/app.sql.gz

echo ls | ./swarm-exec.sh -i app /bin/bash

./swarm-exec.sh -it some_app /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest command I found to `docker exec` into a swarm node (with a swarm manager at `$SWARM_MANAGER_HOST`) running the service `$SERVICE_NAME` (for example `mystack_myservice`) is the following:

```bash
SERVICE_JSON=$(ssh $SWARM_MANAGER_HOST "docker service ps $SERVICE_NAME --no-trunc --format '{{ json . }}' -f desired-state=running")
ssh -t $(echo $SERVICE_JSON | jq -r '.Node') "docker exec -it $(echo $SERVICE_JSON | jq -r '.Name').$(echo $SERVICE_JSON | jq -r '.ID') bash"
```

This asserts that you have ssh access to `$SWARM_MANAGER_HOST` as well as the swarm node currently running the service task.

This also asserts that you have `jq` installed (`apt install jq`), but if you can't or don't want to install it and you have python installed you can create the following alias (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/535203)):

```bash
alias jq="python3 -c 'import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)[sys.argv[2].partition(\".\")[-1]])'"
```

Answer (score 3):

**See addendum 2...**

Example of a oneliner for entering the database `my_db` on node `master`:

`DB_NODE_ID=master && docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name=$DB_NODE_ID) mysql my_db`

In case you want to configure, say `max_connections`:

`DB_NODE_ID=master && $(docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name=$DB_NODE_ID) mysql -e "SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000") && docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name=$DB_NODE_ID) mysql my_db`

This approach allows to enter all database nodes (e.g. slaves) just by setting the `DB_NODE_ID` variable accordingly.

Example for slave `s2`:

`DB_NODE_ID=s2 && docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name=$DB_NODE_ID) mysql my_db`

or

`DB_NODE_ID=s2 && $(docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name=$DB_NODE_ID) mysql -e "SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000") && docker exec -it $(docker ps -q -f name=$DB_NODE_ID) mysql my_db`

Put this into your `KiTTY` or `PuTTY` configuration for `master` / `s2` under Data/Command and you are set.

---

As an addendum:

The old, non swarm mode version reads simply

```
docker exec -it master mysql my_db
```

resp.

```
DB_ID=master && $(docker exec -it $DB_ID mysql -e "SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000") && docker exec -it $DB_ID mysql tmp
```

---

**Addendum 2:**

As it turned out by example, the term `docker ps -q -f name=$DB_NODE_ID` may return wrong values under certain conditions.

The following approach works correctily:

```
docker ps -a  | grep "_$DB_NODE_ID." | awk '{print $1}'
```

You may substitute the examples above accordingly.

---

Addendum 3:

Well, these terms look awful and they certainly are painful to type, so you may want to ease your work. On Linux, everybody knows how to do this. On Windws, you may want to use AHK.

This is the AHK term I use:

```
:*:ii::DB_NODE_ID=$(docker ps -a  | grep "_." | awk '{{}print $1{}}') && docker exec -it $id ash{Left 49}
```

So when I type `ii` -- which is as simple as it can get -- I get the desired term with the cursor in place and just have to fill in the container name.

Answer (score 0):

I edited the script Brian van Rooijen added above. Because my reputation is to low, I cannot add it

```
#! /bin/bash

set -e

service=${1}
shift
task="$*"

echo $task

serviceID=$(docker service ps -f name=$service -f desired-state=running $service -q --no-trunc |head -n1)
node=$(docker service ps -f name=$service -f desired-state=running $service --format="{{.Node}}"| head -n1 )
serviceName=$(docker service ps -f name=$service -f desired-state=running $service --format="{{.Name}}"| head -n1 )


docker -H $node exec -it $serviceName"."$serviceID $task
```

I had the issue that the container didn't exists with the hard coded .1. in the execution.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at my solution: https://github.com/binbrayer/swarmServiceExec.

This approach is based on Docker Machines. I also created the prototype of the script to call containers asynchronously and as a result simultaneously.