# How to docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash on deployed docker stack?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, docker-swarm

I have a deployed docker stack on AWS with swarm:

```
docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-stack.yml pipeline
```

I want to get an interactive bash session into one of the containers defined in the *docker-stack.yml*, but the various `docker exec -ti CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash` invocations that I have tried all fail.

What is the right method to derive a container name to be passed to:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
```

given that:

```
docker service ps pipeline_django
```

returns valid service information and:

```
docker stack ps pipeline
```

returns valid stack information.

None of the documented methods of deriving the container_name from these commands work when passed to the `docker exec -it` command. They all fail with:

> Error response from daemon: No such container

I've tried the things listed here:

[execute a command within docker swarm service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362363/execute-a-command-within-docker-swarm-service)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?  I am surprised it is nearly impossible to locate this in any documentation - such a basic operation.

Comment: You can have a look at [run docker exec from swarm manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44638869/run-docker-exec-from-swarm-manager), especially [BMitch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639230/1885518) where he suggests the usage of [exposing the docker daemon via HTTPS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers failed, because they no not extract the container it from the task. Swarm wraps a task object around a container:

```sh
taskid=$(docker service ps -q ${servicename} |head -1)
containerid=$(docker inspect -f '{{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}' ${taskid})
docker exec -it ${containerid} "$*"
```

Of course, this will only take the first container in the list.

Comment: Even though this might not be strictly necessary, you can additionally filter for only running containers: `docker service ps -qf desired-state=running ${servicename} | head -1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on my local macOS.

```
$ docker stack ls
NAME                SERVICES
gospot_web          1

$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                               PORTS
qigx492p2lbe        gospot_web_web      global              1/1                 gospot/gospot-web:0.1.20.g225306b   *:80->80/tcp, *:443->443/tcp
```

You can use either container id or container name to access the container.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS               NAMES
b3824a85d3c8        gospot/gospot-web:0.1.20.g225306b   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours (healthy)   80/tcp, 443/tcp     gospot_web_web.3cqcd1v22vaon517j7p5h1d9a.wrel676fcllssrm3151ymkse9

$ docker exec -it b3824a85d3c8 sh
/ # ls
bin    etc    lib    mnt    root   sbin   sys    usr
dev    home   media  proc   run    srv    tmp    var
/ #

$ docker exec -it 
gospot_web_web.3cqcd1v22vaon517j7p5h1d9a.wrel676fcllssrm3151ymkse9 sh
/ # ls
bin    dev    etc    home   lib    media  mnt    proc   root   run    
sbin   srv    sys    tmp    usr    var
/ #
```

If the target service name is unique enough, you can use the following one-liner.

```
$ docker exec -it $(docker ps | grep gospot_web_web | awk '{print $1}') sh
/ # ls
bin    etc    lib    mnt    root   sbin   sys    usr
dev    home   media  proc   run    srv    tmp    var
/ #
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command and replace SERVICE_NAME with your service name:

```
docker exec -it \
    $(docker stack ps pipeline| grep SERVICE_NAME | cut -d' ' -f1) /bin/bash
```

this command finds the container id of your service:

```
docker stack ps pipeline| grep SERVICE_NAME | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Comment: @Bencho Naut If you disagree with a proposed answer, the right response is to downvote, which communicates to the author and future visitors that you believe the answer is wrong. Don't edit the answer to reflect what happened to work for you (make another answer if you think there is value).