# Load balanced docker-exec

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We currently have a consumer service that calls producer processes in another container through `docker exec` (and exposed docker socket on the consumer service).

Question: How can such a `docker exec` call be load balanced onto containers running on multiple nodes?

Am I reading [execute a command within docker swarm service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362363/execute-a-command-within-docker-swarm-service) correctly, in that this is not possible currently?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to use `docker exec` for this use case.

Comment: I don't really care whether it's docker exec or something else, but it would be great to have a way to just run commands in a round-robin way across a docker swarm. Coming from HPC applications I thought this would be a no-brainer for a technology stack with that name...

Comment: I tend to recommend job-queueing systems like RabbitMQ for this use case.  `docker exec` can be fragile, has massive security implications, and just doesn’t work in this multi-host case you’re describing.